# Localstorage implementation showing undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Please find my code snippet below. Basically, user is entering username and password from the login screen and when user clicks on it, I am passing the information via Ajax call and if the JSON response contains `SUCCESS` as shown in my check `else if (data_.status == "SUCCESS"){`, I am planning to use HTML5 local storage. But, I am getting `undefined` for the following console log `console.log("Value check for DEMO.value:"+demo.value); // I saw undefined here` which is stopping me from moving forward.Am I doing something wrong? I am following [this tutorial](https://toddmotto.com/storing-data-in-the-browser-with-the-html5-local-storage-api/)

```
$("#submit").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var userNAME = $("#username").val();
     var passWord = $("#password").val();

     var ajaxRequest = jQuery.ajax({
         data: {
           username: userNAME,
           password: passWord
         },
         dataType: "json",
         method: "POST",
         url: loginUrl
       })
       .done(function (data_, textStatus_, jqXHR_) {
           if (data_.status != "SUCCESS") {
             alert(data_.message);
             return false;

           } else if (data_.status == "SUCCESS") {
             var testedValue = $("#userName").html(userNAME);
             var demoValue = $("#userName").val();
             console.log("Value check for userNAME:" + userNAME);

             // Local Storage Stuff Begins
             // Grab the username
             var demo = document.querySelector('#userName');
             console.log("Value check for demo:" + demo); // I can see the username here

             // localStorage feature detect
             function supportsLocalStorage() {
               return typeof (Storage) !== 'undefined';
             }

             if (!supportsLocalStorage()) {
               // Change the value to inform the user of no support
               demo.value = 'No HTML5 localStorage support, soz.';
             } else {
               console.log("Inside Else Statement; This means the browser has HTML5 localstorage support!"); // I can see this message
               console.log("Value check for DEMO.value:" + demo.value); // I saw undefined here

               // Try this
               try {
                 // Set the interval and autosave every second
                 setInterval(function () {
                   localStorage.setItem('autosave', demo.value);
                 }, 1000);
               } catch (e) {
                 // If any errors, catch and alert the user
                 if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
                   alert('Quota exceeded!');
                 }
               }

               // If there is data available
               if (localStorage.getItem('autosave')) {
                 // Retrieve the item
                 demo.value = localStorage.getItem('autosave');
               }
             } // End of Else
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Adding HTML for reference:(I followed [this login dialog](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-login-dialog/))

```
<!-- Login HTML Begins -->
<div id="wrap">
<div id="window" caption="Login">
   <div>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input style="width: 150px;" type="text" name="user" id = "username" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input style="width: 150px;" type="password" name="password" id = "password" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right" valign="bottom">
               <input type="button" id="submit" value="Login" />
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- </div> -->
<!-- Login HTML ends -->
```

the following HTML belogs to the location where I am displaying the `username` on the HTML page (Full code not included )

`<li><a title="Logout" onclick="a" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user whiteIcon"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="userName">`

Comment: try using demo.text()

Comment: Why not use use the variable `demoValue` instead of `demo.value`?

Comment: @vbguyny I was following the same pattern as mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: Please include the HTML to go along with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible for demo.value to be set before you make that console.log

```
if (!supportsLocalStorage())

  demo.value = 'No HTML5 localStorage support, soz.';
```

It get's set as above, if `!supportsLocalStorage()` is true, but you are logging it out in the inverse case. Move your console.log further down the page, to after you have set it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried placing the console `console.log("Testing value of demo.value here: "+demo.value);` below this line`localStorage.setItem('autosave', demo.value);`
and I saw the following `Testing value of demo.value here: [object HTMLSpanElement]`

Similarly, I placed another console log `console.log("Value RETRIEVE Test:"+demo.value);` below line `demo.value = localStorage.getItem('autosave');`
and I noticed the following : `Value RETRIEVE Test:[object HTMLSpanElement]`

Is there a reason why it's not showing actual values? Scope related issues may be?

Comment: @John Look at my answer please. You'll see why you get `[object HTMLSpanElement]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the fact that you are using `document.querySelector('#userName')` instead of `document.querySelector('#username')`.

The following example shows how it should look like, without an ajax request:

http://codepen.io/ovitrif/pen/ENdwrj

PS: Your logic regarding localStorage works.

Another problem, you are using :

```
var demo = document.querySelector('#username');
console.log("Value check for demo:" + demo);
```

This means you are trying to append the element itself to the rest of the text. I think you only want the value, so your code should be:

```
console.log("Value check for demo:" + demo.value);
```

Comment: 1) Changing `console.log("Value check for demo:" + demo);` to `console.log("Value check for demo:" + demo.value);`
still shows me my username 2) However, placing the `console.log("Testing value of demo.value here: "+demo.value);` just below the line 
`localStorage.setItem('autosave', demo.value);` shows `[object HTMLSpanElement]` which is strange.

Comment: Ok, so you were showing only part of the code. Looking at that part, your implementation seemed wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have solution to use one [jQuery Labrary](http://creativform.com/creativetools/documentation#.storage()) what I made and work fine:

```
// check if browser support storage
    if($.storage())
    {
        // Set a session storage
        $.storage('the_storage', 'the_value');

        // Get session storage
        $.storage('the_storage');

        // delete storage
        $.storage('the_storage', null);
    }
    else
    {
        // browser not support, use cookie
        alert("WARNING!!! Your Browser is old and not have Web Storage support.Perhaps you'll have problems using this site.");
    }
```

But I include cookie inside this function and if local storage your browser not support, automaticaly function start using cookie and you not have a problems.

Here is full code function: [GitHub](https://github.com/CreativForm/CreativeTools/blob/master/creative.tools.js#L1661)

Feel free to use it.